# A port address conflict has been detected. LAN Messenger will close now

Tags: linux-mint, serial-port, lan

I have installed *LAN messenger* on *linux mint*.

It was installed successfully but was not running.

So I have tried "**sudo lmc**" in terminal and than it gave the following error in a popup window:

> A port address conflict has been detected. LAN Messenger will close now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command in terminal worked for me.

```
lmc /noconfig
```